# Does sonarlint support c++?

Tags: c++, sonarlint

I'm trying to run sonarlint (2.1.0.566) from command line in order to analyze the c++ code with no success. Same works pretty well in Eclipse with the sonarlint plugin. Also, I'm able to see the analysis results on our sonarqube server.
I run following command:

```
sonarlint --src "src/*.cpp" -X
```

I got following log:

```
DEBUG: Plugins:
DEBUG:   * C / C++ / Objective-C 4.4.0.6266 (cpp)
DEBUG:   * Python 1.6 (python)
DEBUG:   * Java 4.4.0.8066 (java)
DEBUG:   * PHP 2.9.1.1705 (php)
DEBUG:   * JavaScript 2.19.0.3866 (javascript)
DEBUG:   * PL/SQL 2.8 (plsql)
DEBUG:   * Swift 2.0.0.1127 (swift)
```

This is good, it seems that we have a c++ plugin. The next lines are fine as well:

```
DEBUG: Available languages:
DEBUG:   * C => "c"
DEBUG:   * C++ => "cpp"
DEBUG:   * Objective-C => "objc"
DEBUG:   * Python => "py"
DEBUG:   * Java => "java"
DEBUG:   * PHP => "php"
DEBUG:   * JavaScript => "js"
DEBUG:   * PL/SQL => "plsql"
DEBUG:   * Swift => "swift"
```

Yet the following lines are confusing:

```
DEBUG: Start analysis
DEBUG: Declared extensions of language C were converted to c: file:**/*.disabled
DEBUG: Declared extensions of language C++ were converted to cpp: file:**/*.disabled
DEBUG: Declared extensions of language Objective-C were converted to objc: file:**/*.disabled
DEBUG: Declared extensions of language Python were converted to py: file:**/*.py
DEBUG: Declared extensions of language Java were converted to java: file:**/*.java,file:**/*.jav
DEBUG: Declared extensions of language PHP were converted to php: file:**/*.php,file:**/*.php3,file:**/*.php4,file:**/*.php5,file:**/*.phtml,file:**/*.inc
DEBUG: Declared extensions of language JavaScript were converted to js: file:**/*.js
DEBUG: Declared extensions of language PL/SQL were converted to plsql: file:**/*.sql,file:**/*.pks,file:**/*.pkb
DEBUG: Declared extensions of language Swift were converted to swift: file:**/*.swift
```

...

```
INFO: 34 files indexed
DEBUG: 'C' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: 'CPP' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: 'Objective-C' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: 'Python Squid Sensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: 'JavaSquidSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: 'PHP sensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: 'JavaScript Squid Sensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: 'PL/SQL Sensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: 'Swift Squid Sensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
```

Why the c++ extensions are disabled? 
How can I enable it?